# findsecbugs sonar plugin maven build fail

Tags: maven-2, sonarqube, findbugs

I'm currently using sonarqube LTS(4.5.7) with Findsecbugs plugin installed.

The problem is when running mvn clean install with sonar profile the build fail and it says :Failed to clean project,failed to delete C:..\myproject..\findsecbugs.jar

so it's clear that the findsecbugs.jar cannot be removed in the cleaning phase
i've done some research and it seems that Java process is locking the resource.
Is there anyway to solve the problem knowing that if I kill the Java process it will stop mvn Build.

PS: I cannot move to the latest version of sonarqube since generating issues report in publish mode is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by making maven ignore the jar in cleaning phase.